# PagerTabStrip not showing in ViewPager in app targeting Android 6.X (N)

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-support-library, android-7.0-nougat, pagertabstrip

I have an existing app that makes use of `ViewPager` and `PagerTabStrip` and this has been working for a long time with various releases of the Android SDK and the `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` library. I've just bumped up the compile and target SDK versions of my app from `23` to `24` and the `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` library version from `23.4.0` to `24.0.0`... and I now see that the `PagerTabStrip` is totally missing from the `ViewPager`. (Not just missing titles in the `PagerTabStrip`... the `PagerTabStrip` is totally missing from the `ViewPager` when the views are rendered.)

This is how I'm declaring the `ViewPager` and `PagerTabStrip` views in my layout file:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/pagerTabStrip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@color/view_bg_blue" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Can anyone spot something that I'm doing wrong or could this be a bug in `ViewPager` and `PagerTabStrip`?

Comment: Btw, raised an Android support issue here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=214283

Comment: Mine only PagerTabStrip disappeared, not the fragment contents.

Comment: Yes, same as what I see: the pages in the `ViewPager` are visible but not the `PagerTabStrip`. Apologies if that's not clear from my description.

Comment: Not at all, it was very clear, thank you. What I have done so far is I changed the **PagerTabStrip** to **PagerTitleStrip**. This made the title of the fragments appear again, but without the "click" funcionality, i.e.: I had to build an options menu to help sweep fragments for those who cannot figure out how to deal with my pager :(

Comment: There's a workaround suggested here which you might want to try: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=213359 (I haven't had the opportunity to try it yet.)

Comment: Adil, many thanks for your attention. The workaround really worked for me. Very happy with this. Sorry to take your time. God bless.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the temporary workaround until the issue is resolved in the Android support library:

```
((ViewPager.LayoutParams) pagerTabStrip.getLayoutParams()).isDecor = true;
```

See here for a fuller discussion on the status of the issue:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=213359

Comment: This is clearly the answer to the problem. It should get accepted.

Answer (score 0):

```
We’ll start with the layout for our activity (**activity_pager_tab_strip.xml**), which in this case will just be a ViewPager containing a PagerTabStrip:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUvF9.png

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
public class PagerTabStripActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pager_tab_strip);
        TabsPagerAdapter adapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
Example: http://photo-wonder.blogspot.com/2016/09/using-pagertabstrip-with-viewpager.html
```

Comment: tienanhcntt2, please read the question and the accepted answer in this thread. There was a bug in the Android Support library. It is resolved now.