# PagerTabStrip is not showing

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am making swipe tab view. I want to show PagerTabStrip at bottom of SupportActionBar. All the tabs contents showing well but the problem is the title of these tabs not showing also PagerTabStrip is not showing on the bottom of SupportActionBar.

main_tab.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#e62117"
            android:id="@+id/tab_strip"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false">
        </android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip>

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

tab1, tab2, tab3: similar

```
  public class tab1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1,container,false);
return view;
    }
}
```

ma_page_adapter:

```
public class ma_pager_adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public ma_pager_adapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {

        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                tab1 t1 = new tab1();
                return t1;
            case 1:
                tab2 t2 = new tab2();
                return t2;
            case 2:
                tab3 t3 = new tab3();
                return t3;

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }//set the number of tabs

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Top stories";
            case 1:

                return "Members";
            case 2:

                return "Setting";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
   ViewPager pager;
    PagerTabStrip tab_strp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_tab);
        ma_pager_adapter mapager = new ma_pager_adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


        pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(mapager);
//        tab_strp = (PagerTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tab_strip);
        ((ViewPager.LayoutParams) findViewById(R.id.tab_strip).getLayoutParams()).isDecor = true;
//        tab_strp.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line from your `tab1.onCreateView(...)` method...

```
((ViewPager.LayoutParams) (view.findViewById(R.id.tab_strip)).getLayoutParams()).isDecor = true;
```

... and add it to your `MainActivity.onCreate(...)` method. Your app will stop crashing.

Your `tab1` Fragment class has no knowledge of the `R.id.tab_strip` view. That is a view of the `MainActivity` class.

Comment: Dude, I can't see why your app is crashing from the code you have pasted in your question. Please create a separate Stack Overflow question that shows the code and the stack trace of the crash and we'l get to the bottom of it. The answer by @L.Liu seems to suggest that the code in your question is fine and it's probably something else that you're doing in your app that's causing it to crash. Like I said, create a separate question, show me the stack trace of the crash, send me the link and we'll investigate.

Answer (score 2):

Your question duplicates the issue below:

[PagerTabStrip not showing in ViewPager in app targeting Android 6.X (N)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38037785/pagertabstrip-not-showing-in-viewpager-in-app-targeting-android-6-x-n)

For apps targeting Android N, you need to use the following workaround:

In onCreateView(), add the following:

((ViewPager.LayoutParams) (view.findViewById(R.id.tab_strip)).getLayoutParams()).isDecor = true;

Comment: i add this line in onCreate() but its gives fatal error. kindly tell me how to exactly add this code to my activity class.

Comment: this Activity code gives eroror..........ViewPager pager;
    PagerTabStrip tab_strp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_tab);

        ma_pager_adapter mapager = new ma_pager_adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        PagerTabStrip tab_strp = (PagerTabStrip)findViewById(R.id.tab_strip);
        ((ViewPager.LayoutParams) tab_strp.getLayoutParams()).isDecor = true;
        pager.setAdapter(mapager);


    }

Comment: Please add the line to onCreateView().

Comment: I already added line in my code but there is fatal error appears.

Comment: Right after you get the view (after line 1). What does your onCreateView() look like? Can you update your code and also add the exception you are getting?

Comment: onCreateView() is in tab1 which extends Fragment.

Comment: ok i've update my code. still getting fatal error please see edited code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117432/discussion-between-bc120201817-zohaib-siddiq-and-parag-goel).

Answer (score 2):

I have run your code,its running normal.If you want to show it on the bottom  of yours ViewPager,you may use"android:layout_gravity "and set it bottom.

Comment: My tabs were behind my toolbar... thanks for the clue.